# Layer weights don't match in keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow

This question uses the following code:

```
Xtrain = np.random.rand(400,1)
ytrain = f(Xtrain)
Xval = np.random.rand(200,1)
yval = f(Xval)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
             )

model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=500, verbose=0)
```

Using the command `model.layers[0].get_weights()` I get the following output:

```
[array([[-0.43412966, -0.51346564, -0.14263666,  0.8693182 , -0.4930619 ,
          1.249465  , -0.3924656 , -0.48984256, -0.55827504,  0.11134321]],
       dtype=float32),
 array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.34663308,  0.        ,
         0.36201355,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.11139664],
       dtype=float32)]
```

And using `model.layers[1].get_weights()` I get this:

```
[array([[-0.04339373],
        [ 0.19533908],
        [-0.2295354 ],
        [ 0.903574  ],
        [-0.17581558],
        [ 0.7272965 ],
        [-0.69347996],
        [ 0.02008992],
        [-0.30351916],
        [-0.29846227]], dtype=float32),
 array([0.29466572], dtype=float32)]
```

**I don't understand why the outgoing weights from layer 0 (second array in the `model.layers[0].get_weights()` list) don't match the incoming weights for layer 1 (first array in the `model.layers[1].get_weights()` list).** And why is there an outgoing weight from layer 1? Isn't that supposed to be the final layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Expected shape of parameter arrays

Each layer has two arrays:

- one for the **weights**, which has a shape of `(num_inputs, num_outpus)`
- one for the **biases**, which has a shape of `(num_outputs)`

Here the `num_inputs` is the number of input features **to that layer** and the `num_outputs` is the number of outputs **from that layer** (this is what you select when instantiating a layer).

#### Output of `.get_weights()`

Another important thing to note is the usage of `.get_weights()`. In fact there are to ways to use it:

- From **the model**, i.e. `model.get_weights()`: This will return a **flattened** list containing all parameter arrays in order. For example, it could look like this: `[layer1_weights, layer1_biases, layer2_weights, layer2_biases, ...]`
- From **a layer**, i.e. `layer.get_weights()`: This is what you used. Here it will return the parameter arrays for a given layer. For example `model.layers[1].get_weights()` will return the parameter arrays for `layer1`. If `layer1` has biases then this will return two arrays, one for the weights and one for the biases.

---

I took the liberty of changing your code a bit to make this a bit more clear.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

f = lambda x: 2*x

Xtrain = np.random.rand(400, 5)  # 5 input features
ytrain = f(Xtrain)
Xval = np.random.rand(200, 5)  # 5 input features
yval = f(Xval)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),  # this layer has 5 inputs and 10 outputs
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')  # this layer has 10 inputs and 1 output
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
             )

model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=1, verbose=0)

# I will be calling .get_weights() directly from the model,
# so we expect 4 arrays: 2 for each layer.
 
print('First layer weights:', model.get_weights()[0].shape)
print('First layer biases:', model.get_weights()[1].shape)
print('Second layer weights:', model.get_weights()[2].shape)
print('Second layer biases:', model.get_weights()[3].shape)
```

The output:

```
First layer weights: (5, 10)  
First layer biases: (10,)  
Second layer weights: (10, 1)  
Second layer biases: (1,)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear answer!